# Object not spawning on ground

Tags: 8thwall-xr

Even trying all the combination of settings combination of XR Surface Controller. Everytime gameobeject is in air. Even tried moving the camera in Y axis and focusing on object from above. Even the demo project have same issues. How to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this issue?

Comment: To add to what sɐunıɔןɐqɐp mentioned, can you provide some details on the device you're attempting this with? Any screenshots of the behavior? How did you try setting up & running the sample project?

Comment: Additionally, I would first check that the game object (i.e your 3D Plane) with XRSurfaceController attached should be positioned at a height of Y=0.  What type of device are you using?